# How to remove the backslash from properties value in java

Tags: java, properties-file

I have read and tried following

- [How to remove the backslash in string using regex in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242417/how-to-remove-the-backslash-in-string-using-regex-in-java)
- [Java, Removing backslash in string object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104192/java-removing-backslash-in-string-object)
- [String replace a Backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596458/string-replace-a-backslash)

and many blog as well but all are for removing from string not for properties file

I am trying to remove **`\`** from properties file value but no luck

Here is my `config.properties` file

```
query=select * from users
field=id
```

and my Java code that is `A.java` is

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String configPath = "/home/arif/util-test/config.properties";
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream configFileInputStream =  new FileInputStream(configPath);
        prop.load(configFileInputStream);
        System.out.println("Property file loaded "+ configPath);
        configFileInputStream.close();
        String query = prop.getProperty("query");
        query += " where " + prop.getProperty("field") + " = 1";
        //query = query.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
        query = query.replace("\\", "");
        prop.replace("query", query);
        prop.store(new FileOutputStream(configPath), null);
        System.out.println("updated query="+ query);
    }

}
```

and updated `config.properties` file

```
#Mon Oct 03 14:34:27 IST 2016
query=select * from users where id \= 1
field=id
```

while I am expecting following

```
#Mon Oct 03 14:34:27 IST 2016
query=select * from users where id = 1
field=id
```

and getting expected output from terminal or cmd, terminal output is

```
Property file loaded /home/arif/util-test/config.properties
updated query=select * from users where id = 1
```

your help will be appreciated! thank you

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Have you read question before marking duplicate?

Comment: @PeterLawrey this is not the same subject here, the problem here is the fact that `=` is special character in properties file as it is used to slit the key and the value of a given property such that it will always be escaped with a backslash but it is totally transparent for the end user as calling `getProperty("query")` will return the value without the backslash

Comment: Why do you want to remove the backslash as it is transparent for you? it is only an implementation detail

Comment: thank you @NicolasFilotto, I was thinking that I can not execute with `\` but it is working fine when I load it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove the use of `\` from a properties file as this is how a Properties file is defined to be implemented.

From the Javadoc for [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

> All of these key termination characters may be included in the key by escaping them with a preceding backslash character; for example,
>
> ```
> \:\=
> ```

This line

```
query=select * from users where id = 1
```

is not valid as it contains two unescaped `=` characters. The second one needs to be escaped out.

You could implement properties differently to not need this, but it wouldn't be a standard Properties file.

Alternative ways of storing properties are XML, JSON and YAML.  I prefer YAML which is generally simpler/cleaner to read.

Spec for Yaml http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html

Java Library for YAML https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml This is a good library for configuration. I would start with this.

Comment: thanks for your recommendation, YAML syntax really looks better than properties file

Comment: @ArifKhan Properties were developed for Java 1.0 and are builtin but dump.

Comment: @ArifKhan added some links.